# Problems using vectors for a negamax algorithm c++

Tags: c++

Ok, so this is my first time asking my own question on stack overflow, so I hope I am in the right place, but here goes:

I am trying to write a program that can do a total solve of the game Abalone - at least in theory, even if there isn't the computational power to do it.
I am using vectors to hold the board positions, and use MAX_SIZE to indicate the length of the longest diagonal on the board.  The code appears to work correctly for the board with sides length 2 (meaning MAX_SIZE of 3), returning -2 for player 1 win, 0 for draw, and 2 for player 2 win, but it throws an error when I try to increase MAX_SIZE.

I think the problem is occurring in my legality_check() function, but I can't figure out where. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will include the entirety of my code so you can compile and run it (hope that's ok), but will also tell you where I think the problem is.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <map>
#include <string>
const int MAX_DEPTH = 100;
const int MAX_SIZE = 3;
const int WINNING_SCORE = 2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> starting_vector(MAX_SIZE, std::vector<int>(MAX_SIZE));
std::map<std::vector<std::vector<int>>, std::vector<int>> positions_checked;

//checks legality of specified move and then performs the move if it is legal
std::vector<std::vector<int>> legality_check(std::vector<std::vector<int>> initial_pos, int posr, int posc, int direction)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> new_pos(initial_pos);
    int start_posr = posr;
    int start_posc = posc;
    //weight keeps track of the weight of the 2 players separately and adds them together at the end
    //the result of the addition (mod 10) gives the function the result it should return
    int weight[2] = {0, 0};
    //Keeps track of when the color of the marbles changes to the opponents
    bool player_changed = false;
    //the color of the marble in the starting position
    int color;
    //how much the program will have the row and column increment by each iteration.
    int row_move;
    int column_move;
    int score = 0;
    int buffer = 0;
    if (posc >= MAX_SIZE)
    {
        buffer = posc - MAX_SIZE + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer = 0;
    }
    bool out_of_bounds = false; //not ((posr>buffer and posc>=0) and (posr<(signed)initial_pos.size() and posc<(signed)initial_pos[posr].size()));


    //Calculates row_move and column_move. Will follow the below pattern:
    //direction 0: [posr][posc+1] each time
    //direction 1: [posr-1][posc] each time
    //direction 2: [posr-1][posc-1] each time
    //direction 3: [posr][posc-1] each time
    //direction 4: [posr+1][posc] each time
    //direction 5: [posr+1][posc+1] each time
    switch (direction)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        row_move = 0;
        column_move = 1;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        row_move = -1;
        column_move = 0;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        row_move = -1;
        column_move = -1;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        row_move = 0;
        column_move = -1;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        row_move = 1;
        column_move = 0;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        row_move = 1;
        column_move = 1;
        break;
    }
    //if it is not one of the above directions, it is a bad function call and thus an illegal move
    default: return initial_pos;
    }
    //Stores color of starting position marble
    color = initial_pos[posr][posc];
    if (color == 0)
    {
        return initial_pos;
    }
    //while not out of bounds of the board or not on an empty square
    while (not out_of_bounds and initial_pos[posr][posc] != 0)
    {
        //if the current position's marble is not the same as color, the marbles will now be of the other player
        if (initial_pos[posr][posc] != color)
        {
            player_changed = true;
        }
        //if 2 marble colors have been checked, and we see the original color again, it is an illegal move
        if (player_changed)
        {
            if (initial_pos[posr][posc] == color)
            {
                return initial_pos;
            }
            //otherwise, add the marble's weight to the player total
            weight[1] = (weight[1] + initial_pos[posr][posc]) % (MAX_SIZE + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            //add marble's weight to player total
            weight[0] = (weight[0] + initial_pos[posr][posc]) % (MAX_SIZE + 1);
        }
        posr += row_move;
        posc += column_move;
        if (posc >= MAX_SIZE)
        {
            buffer = posc - MAX_SIZE + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = 0;
        }
        out_of_bounds = not ((posr > buffer and posc >= 0) and (posr < (signed)initial_pos.size() and posc < (signed)initial_pos[posr].size()));
    }
    if (out_of_bounds)
    {
        score = 1;
        posr -= row_move;
        posc -= column_move;
    }
    weight[0] = weight[0] / color;
    //the formula (color*MAX_SIZE)%(MAX_SIZE+1) switches the value of color to the opposing players values due to how I
    //chose the numbers that represent each color (1 for 1 player, MAX_SIZE for the other player)
    weight[1] = weight[1] / ((color * MAX_SIZE) % (MAX_SIZE + 1));
    int final_weight = weight[0] - weight[1];
    if (weight[0] <= 3 and final_weight > 0)
    {

        while (posr != start_posr and posc != start_posc)
        {
            new_pos[posr][posc] = new_pos[posr - row_move][posc - column_move];
            posr -= row_move;
            posc -= column_move;
        }
        new_pos[start_posr][start_posc] = 0;

        if (positions_checked.count(new_pos) == 0)
        {
            positions_checked[new_pos] = std::vector<int>(3, 0);

        }
        if (color == 1)
        {
            //positions_checked[new_pos][0]+=score+positions_checked[initial_pos][0]; ???

            positions_checked[new_pos][0] += score;


        }
        else
        {
            //positions_checked[new_pos][1]+=score+positions_checked[initial_pos][1]; ???
            positions_checked[new_pos][1] += score;

        }

        return new_pos;

    }
    else
    {
        return initial_pos;
    }
}
int negamax(std::vector<std::vector<int>> initial_pos, int depth, int color, bool prev_move)
{
    int best_value=-10000;
    int value;
    int score=0;
    int buffer=0;
    bool loop_entered=false;


    if(color==1)
    {
        score=positions_checked[initial_pos][1];

    }
    else
    {
        score=positions_checked[initial_pos][0];
    }

    //implement position repetition check later
    if(depth==0 or score>=WINNING_SCORE)
    {
        return -score;
    }
    else
    {

        for(int column=0; column < (signed)initial_pos.size(); ++column)
        {
            if(column>=MAX_SIZE)
            {
                buffer=column-MAX_SIZE+1;
            }
            else
            {
                buffer=0;
            }
            for(int row = buffer; row < (signed)initial_pos[column].size(); ++row)
            {
                if(initial_pos[column][row]==color)
                {
                    bool found_legal_move=false;

                    for(int direction=0; direction!=6; direction++)
                    {
                        std::vector<std::vector<int>> new_pos = legality_check(initial_pos, column, row, direction);
                        if(MAX_SIZE==3)
                        {
                            new_pos[0][MAX_SIZE+2]=(color*MAX_SIZE)%(MAX_SIZE+1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            new_pos[0][MAX_SIZE]=(color*MAX_SIZE)%(MAX_SIZE+1);
                        }
                        if(new_pos != initial_pos && positions_checked[new_pos][2]==0)
                        {
                            found_legal_move=true;
                            positions_checked[new_pos][2]=1;

                            value = negamax(new_pos, depth-1, (color*MAX_SIZE)%(MAX_SIZE+1),true);

                            //color 1: score 2. Return 2. Color 2 receives 2. Becomes -2. 
                            //color1: score -1. Return -1. Color 2 receives -1. Becomes 1. Returns 1.
                            //color1 receives 1. Becomes -1.;
                            //color1 receives -1. Becomes 1.
                            best_value = std::max(best_value, value);



                        }
                    }
                    if((not found_legal_move) and prev_move)
                    {
                            value = negamax(initial_pos, depth-1, (color*MAX_SIZE)%(MAX_SIZE+1), false);
                            best_value = std::max(best_value, value);
                    }
                    else if((not found_legal_move) and (not prev_move))
                    {
                        return 0; //stalemate, neither player has a legal move, so it is a draw
                    }
                    loop_entered=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(loop_entered==false)
        {
            //if the color has no marbles, the opponent has won
            return WINNING_SCORE;
        }

    }
    return best_value*-1;

}

int main()
{

    starting_vector[(MAX_SIZE-1)/2].resize(MAX_SIZE);
    starting_vector[0].resize(MAX_SIZE);
    starting_vector[0][0] = 1;
    starting_vector[0][1] = 1;
    starting_vector[1][0] = 1;
    starting_vector[1][1] = 1;
    starting_vector[1][2] = 0;
    starting_vector[2][0] = MAX_SIZE;
    starting_vector[2][1] = MAX_SIZE;
    starting_vector[0][MAX_SIZE+2]=1;
    positions_checked[starting_vector] = std::vector<int>(3,0);
    std::cout << starting_vector.size() << " " << starting_vector[0].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<starting_vector[0][0] << " " << starting_vector[0][1] << " " << starting_vector[1][0]
                                     << " " << starting_vector[1][1] << " " << starting_vector[1][2]
                                     << " " << starting_vector[2][0] << " " << starting_vector[2][1]
                                     << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> new_vector(legality_check(starting_vector, 0, 0, 1));
    std::cout<<new_vector[0][0] << " " << new_vector[0][1] << " " << new_vector[1][0]
                                     << " " << new_vector[1][1] << " " << new_vector[1][2]
                                     << " " << new_vector[2][0] << " " << new_vector[2][1]
                                     << std::endl;

    std::cout<<starting_vector[0][0] << " " << starting_vector[0][1] << " " << starting_vector[1][0]
                                     << " " << starting_vector[1][1] << " " << starting_vector[1][2]
                                     << " " << starting_vector[2][0] << " " << starting_vector[2][1]
                                     << std::endl;
    std::cout<<new_vector[0][2] << std::endl;
    std::cout<<negamax(starting_vector, MAX_DEPTH, 1,true)<< " Returned successfully" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, that's a lot of code, but here's what's happening. I run the code and it gives me a "*** Error in './abalone.exe':free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001c8f0b0 ***" Aborted (core dumped). But the error, and I might be wrong on this, seems to be occurring only after my last cout returns - the line immediately before the return in int main(), which doesn't make any sense, since the program outputs 6 lines, and I only have 6 couts. That is confusing me, since the only code after that last cout is the return.

Also, it wasn't a segmentation fault, I had gotten this code mixed up with some other code I was working on, I am sorry about that.

I did a backtrace with gdb and got this after the program threw the exception:

```
*** Error in '/abalone.exe': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000060b0b0 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7313cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7313cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff73170d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7350394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff745eb28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff735c66e in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>,
    str=0x7ffff745ecc8 "free(): invalid next size (fast)", action=1)
    at malloc.c:4996
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0)
    at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x000000000040457c in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsign
ed long) ()
#6  0x0000000000403694 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deall
ocate(int*, unsigned long) ()
#7  0x0000000000402b25 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector
_base() ()
#8  0x00000000004023f9 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() ()
#9  0x0000000000405191 in void std::_Destroy<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int
> > >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*) ()
#10 0x00000000004047cf in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::vector<i
nt, std::allocator<int> >*>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector
<int, std::allocator<int> >*) ()
#11 0x00000000004039a0 in void std::_Destroy<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Is there any more information I need to give to help you guys help me?

Comment: Did you step through your program with a debugger?

Comment: Yes could you at least tell us the line causing the seg fault.

Comment: Why don't you try debugging the code? You know, the internet is a wonderful idea, but also a curse, many people just stop thinking/researching for themselves. Whenever you spend time and solve a problem, be it as trivial, you feel a huge satisfaction, much more than getting an answer from a website. So try to think for yourself first, post what you tried, and what the issue may be. Why do you think the error is in your `legality_check()` function? How can you test it? What may the issues be? And also, start with small code, test it, then move on. No one here is going to debug your 200 ln code.

Comment: Also, `int main()` is missing, so it's really impossible to test your code. I am voting to close the question as it is not appropriate for StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Please don't close it. I am working on addressing what you guys have told me already. I will get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: I took some time to think about the problem more so I could be more clear and accurate about what seems to be happening, so I hope this is a little better.

Comment: @Chris Don't worry if it get's closed, it's just a misnamed "on-hold" so people do not start posting ideas that might turn out totally useless once necessary details are given. I'm pretty sure it would get re-opened. Nonetheless reducing the problem to a minimal example is a great way to get a fast good answer. Or figure it out by yourself during the process.

Comment: @luk32 Thank you, I had misunderstood what closing it meant. I will start trying to reduce it to a minimal example, although I will still appreciate any help anyone can give in the meanwhile.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work for `MAX_SIZE 3`. In `main()` the second line should be `starting_vector[0].resize(MAX_SIZE+3);` (later you have `starting_vector[0][MAX_SIZE+2]=1;`) I get a debug error for the first occurrence of `positions_checked[new_pos][2]` (it doesn't like the `2`). What output is it expected to have? You can edit your original question and add more stuff to the end, don't put it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using the method that lux32 and vsoftco recommended to me let me figure out where the error was occurring and how to fix it.  The line in `int main()` that is `starting_vector[0][MAX_SIZE+2]=1;`
is trying to set a value that is out of bounds of the vector, which would result in undefined behavior. What is needed to be used is `starting_vector[0].push_back(1)`. This increases the size of starting_vector by 1 and sets that location to 1, which is what I needed to do.  Thank you for your help everybody!